# Creating a php hyperlink using variables

Tags: php, variables

I am using a PHP code from several different files that validates a log-in then redirects the user to a success page. On the page I would like to welcome the user and then give them a link that redirects them to their personal service page.

This is the validation code

```
<?php
$host="host"; // Host name 
$username="admin"; // Mysql username 
$password="********"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="users"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

// Check if Remember Me is Checked
if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
    $remember = $_POST['remember'];
    if ($remember == 'rememberme') {
        $remember = 'checked';
    }
}
if($remember='checked' && $count==1){
    setcookie("extendloginwwd", "$myusername", time()+50400);
    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file
"http://mydomain.co.cc/php/login_success.php"
    $_SESSION['username'] = "myusername";
    $_SESSION['password'] = "mypassword";
    header("location:http://mydomain.co.cc/php/login_success.php");
}
elseif($count==1){
    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file
"http://mydomain.co.cc/php/login_success.php"
    $_SESSION['username'] = "myusername";
    $_SESSION['password'] = "mypassword";
    header("location:http://mydomain.co.cc/php/login_success.php");
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

That works fine I have no problems with it. The login_success.php file is the trouble maker.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Success</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="http://mydomain.co.cc/common.css">
        <?php 
            $user=$username;
            $userdir="http://wolffwebdesign.co.cc/$user";
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login Successfull!</h1>
        <p>Welcome <?php echo "$user"?>! Click <?php echo "<a href=$userdir>here</a>";?> to visit your service page to see how we are doing!
    </body>
</html>
```

Let's say that $myusername="john". I would want the page to display something like:

> Welcome John! Click [here](http://mydomain.co.cc/john) to visit your
>   service page to see how we are doing!

Notice it says the username and also the link leads to mydomain.co.cc/**john**

Instead I get something like:

> Welcome ! Click [here](http://mydomain.co.cc) to visit you service page to
>   see how we are doing!

Notice it does not says the username and the link leads back to my homepage.

Thank you for any help provided.

Comment: Where would you expect the variable `$user` to be coming from on that page?

Comment: Just out of interest, why are you using both `stripslashes` and `mysql_real_escape_string` on the user/pw variables? Using just the last one should be sufficient. In this case if a user were to have a slash in their password, they will never be able to login.

Comment: @deceze that was a typo I have fixed it.

Comment: @Oldskool I am not 100% why I have both of them, I am pretty sure I was given that part of the code by a friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes because you put like this `$username=$user` and you do not initialize $user anywhere. To initializae $user you should do `$user=$username` but keep in mind that $username is actually the username from the mysql database.

In PHP

$variable (before = means this gets the value) = $value (after = means this is the value to be taken)

Better do `$user = $_SESSION['username']`

Comment: Thanks that fixed part of it now at least it displays _something_ now it just displays Welcome myusername! instead of, in the case I used above Welcome John!

Answer (score 0):

You should save all user data in the session ($_SESSION['user']) which holds all the data you fetched with your sql query. So username, (real)name, etc. On the welcome page you could then personalize your text with e.g. "Welcom "

Comment: I have attempted this using the following `<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_COOKIE["extendedloginwwd"]))
 $name="Welcome " . $_COOKIE["user"] . "!<br />";
elseif (isset($_COOKIE["loginwwd"]))
 $name="Welcome " . $_COOKIE["user"] . "!<br />";
else
 $name=//form
?>` Then later in my code where I want the welcome message/log-in form to be, I used `<?php echo $name?>` is this what you meant?